# Compare the values in two columns and extract the values of a third column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Compare the values in two columns and extract the values of a third column in a dataframe

df =

| Location | teams | goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | B | 6 |
| 2 | A | 7 |
| 2 | B | 5 |
| 2 | C | 6 |
| 3 | B | 7 |

Expected output df =

| Location | A Team | A Team goals | B Team | B Team Goals | C Team | C Team goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 0 | NA | 1 | 7 | 0 | NA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
data = {'Location': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3},
        'teams': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B'},
        'goals': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

**First**

aggregation with `groupby`

```
(df.groupby(['Location', 'teams'])['goals'].agg(['count', sum])
 .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))
```

output:

```
teams   A               B               C
        count   sum     count   sum     count   sum
Location                        
1       1.0     5.0     1.0     6.0     NaN     NaN
2       1.0     7.0     1.0     5.0     1.0     6.0
3       NaN     NaN     1.0     7.0     NaN     NaN
```

**Second**

Let's create `idx` to change columns

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['teams'].unique(), ['Team', 'Team Goal']]).map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

`idx`

```
Index(['A Team', 'A Team Goal', 'B Team', 'B Team Goal', 'C Team', 'C Team Goal'], dtype='object')
```

**Last**

change columns and `reset_index` (include First code)

```
(df.groupby(['Location', 'teams'])['goals'].agg(['count', sum])
 .unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
 .set_axis(idx, axis=1).reset_index())
```

**output**

```
    Location    A Team  A Team Goal B Team  B Team Goal C Team  C Team Goal
0   1           1.0     5.0         1.0     6.0         NaN     NaN
1   2           1.0     7.0         1.0     5.0         1.0     6.0
2   3           NaN     NaN         1.0     7.0         NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the dataframe using pivot to get the goals. Check for the non null values in `goals` to identify the `teams` then `join` to get the result

```
goals = df.pivot(*df.columns)
teams = s.notna().astype(int)

teams.add_suffix(' Team').join(goals.add_suffix(' Team Goals'))
```

Result

```
teams     A Team  B Team  C Team  A Team Goals  B Team Goals  C Team Goals
Location                                                                  
1              1       1       0           5.0           6.0           NaN
2              1       1       1           7.0           5.0           6.0
3              0       1       0           NaN           7.0           NaN
```

Comment: You forgot to define `s` (I guess it's `goals`). Also you should avoid the `pivot(*df.columns)` trick, it's unclear and soon it won't work anyway as `pivot`/`pivot_table` will become keyword only.